# what sqlite db query for get last row records with specific string id

Tags: android, database, sqlite, fetch

how can i get last row for check that user check in or check out.
this is my database helper class query:

```
public List<UserEntry> getAllUserLastEntryType(String s) {
    List<UserEntry> codeList = new ArrayList<UserEntry>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_USER_ENTRY + " WHERE " + KEY_USER_ID_ENTRY + "=" + s;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    System.out.println("cursor:" + cursor.isLast());

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            UserEntry user = new UserEntry();
            user.setIdCode(cursor.getString(1));
            user.setUserCheckType((cursor.getString(4)));
            // Adding contact to list
            codeList.add(user);
        } while (cursor.moveToLast());
    }

    // return contact list
    return codeList;
}
```

this is activity class, there i fetch record:

```
String userId = PreferencesUtils.getString(UserActivity.this, PreferencesUtils.PREF_KEY_USER_ID_ENTRY, "");
    Log.e("userId", userId);

    List<UserEntry> userEntries = databaseHandler.getAllUserLastEntryType(userId);

    for (UserEntry userEntry : userEntries) {
        String id = userEntry.getIdCode();
        Log.e("checkId", id);
        String type = userEntry.getUserCheckType();
        Log.e("checkType", type);
    }
```

but is returns nothing. please advise me.

Comment: what is datatype of KEY_USER_ID_ENTRY

Comment: datatype of KEY_USER_ID_ENTRY is text

Answer (score 1):

I changed two syntax in your function, please check your function

```
public List<UserEntry> getAllUserLastEntryType(String s) {
        List<UserEntry> codeList = new ArrayList<UserEntry>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_USER_ENTRY + " WHERE " + KEY_USER_ID_ENTRY + " = '" +s+"'";

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        System.out.println("cursor:" + cursor.isLast());

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                UserEntry user = new UserEntry();
                user.setIdCode(cursor.getString(1));
                user.setUserCheckType((cursor.getString(4)));
                // Adding contact to list
                codeList.add(user);
            } while (cursor.moveToLast());
        }

        // return contact list
        return codeList;
    }
```

I used `getReadableDatabase` and made correction in select query, you can also find out if `codeList` count in even, means user is checked out or if its odd, user is checked in. Its totally depend on your programming logic. And also check `cursor.getString` for correct parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You issue is potentially due to **`s`** not being in quotes i.e. your SQL for the query is

`String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_USER_ENTRY + " WHERE " + KEY_USER_ID_ENTRY + "=" + s;`

You will probably find that `String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_USER_ENTRY + " WHERE " + KEY_USER_ID_ENTRY + "='" + s "'";`

would work.

Assuming that the value is correct for example lets say id is stored as the string 001 and "001" is passed as paremeter s. Without the quotes SQLite is being told to consider the value as a number, this it is **1** not **001** and 1 is not what is stored.

However, although perhaps a little lengthier using the `SQLiteDatabase` `query` method is often regarded as the preferable way of querying.

The equivalent, using query, could be:-

```
    String whereclause = KEY_USER_ID_ENTRY + "=?";
    String[] whereargs = {s};
    Cursor cursor = db.query(
        TABLE_USER_ENTRY,     // Table (can include JOINS with ON here)
        null,                 // String array of columns to include, null equivalent to *
        whereclause,          // WHERE (less WHERE) with optional ?'s as placeholders
        whereargs,            // arguments to replace placeholders
        null,                 // GROUP BY (less GROUP BY) clause, null no clause
        null,                 // HAVING (less HAVING), null no clause
        null                  // ORDER BY (LESS ORDER BY), null no clause
    );                        // optional LIMIT
```

So `String whereclause = KEY_USER_ID_ENTRY + "=?";` is equivalent to `WHERE KEY_USER_ID_ENTRY =something` where something is obtained from the **whereargs** string array so in this case it is **`s`** as passed to the method when it is called. So if called with FRED then the query will use the equivalent of `WHERE KEY_USER_ID_ENTRY ='FRED'`.

---

#### illustration

To illustrate the difference based upon your specific issue, consider the following methods in you SQLiteOpenHelper subcclass :-

```
public List<UserEntry> getAllUserLastEntryType(String s) {
    List<UserEntry> codeList = new ArrayList<UserEntry>();
    List<UserEntry> codeListAlternate1 = new ArrayList<UserEntry>();
    List<UserEntry> codeListAlternate2 = new ArrayList<UserEntry>();


    // Existing where s is not enclosed in quotes
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_USER_ENTRY + " WHERE " + KEY_USER_ID_ENTRY + "=" + s;
    Cursor csr;
    /*
    while (csr.moveToNext()) {
        UserEntry user = new UserEntry();
        user.setIDCode(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(KEY_USER_ID_ENTRY)));
        user.setUserCheck(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(USER_TYPE)));
        codeList.add(user);
    }
    */
    addUsersToList(codeList,csr = db.rawQuery(selectQuery,null),"METHOD1",s);
    Log.d("METHDO1", "Raw Query returned " + csr.getCount() + " Rows using SQL=" + selectQuery);

    String alt1Query = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_USER_ENTRY + " WHERE " + KEY_USER_ID_ENTRY + "='" + s + "'";
    addUsersToList(codeListAlternate1,csr = db.rawQuery(alt1Query,null),"METHOD2",s);
    Log.d("METHDO2", "Raw Query returned " + csr.getCount() + " Rows using SQL=" + alt1Query);


    String whereclause = KEY_USER_ID_ENTRY + "=?";
    String[] whereargs = {s};
    addUsersToList(codeListAlternate2,
            db.query(TABLE_USER_ENTRY,null,whereclause,whereargs,null,null,null),
            "METHOD3",s);

    csr.close();

    return codeListAlternate2;

}

private void addUsersToList(List<UserEntry> ulist, Cursor csr, String logtag, String s) {
    csr.moveToPosition(-1); // just in case ensure cursor is before first
    Log.d(logtag,"Rows in Cursor = "+ csr.getCount() + " Based upon Search criteria ===>" + s + "<===");
    while (csr.moveToNext()) {
        UserEntry u = new UserEntry();
        u.setIDCode(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(KEY_USER_ID_ENTRY)));
        u.setUserCheck(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(USER_TYPE)));
        ulist.add(u);
        Log.d(logtag,"Add User IDCode=" + u.getIDCode() + " Check=" + u.getUserCheck());
    }
}
```

Using the following from an activity (*`SO46195289DBHelper` being that helper above*) :-

```
    SO46195289DBHelper dbhlpr = new SO46195289DBHelper(this);
    dbhlpr.insertUser("001","FRED FLINSTONE","fredflistone@toons.com","TYPE1"); //insert test data
    dbhlpr.insertUser("002","BERT REYNOLDS","bertyreynolds@iamamoviestar.com","TYEP2"); // insert test data
    dbhlpr.insertUser("003","TOM HANKS","tomhanks@iamamoviestar.com","TYPE3"); // inert test data
    List<UserEntry> list1 = dbhlpr.getAllUserLastEntryType("001");
    dbhlpr.getAllUserLastEntryType("003"); // test all three methods
```

Then the output would be like :-

```
09-14 14:02:03.817 3562-3562/? D/METHOD1: Rows in Cursor = 0 Based upon Search criteria ===>001<===
09-14 14:02:03.817 3562-3562/? D/METHDO1: Raw Query returned 0 Rows using SQL=SELECT  * FROM users WHERE keyuseridentry=001
09-14 14:02:03.818 3562-3562/? D/METHOD2: Rows in Cursor = 1 Based upon Search criteria ===>001<===
09-14 14:02:03.818 3562-3562/? D/METHOD2: Add User IDCode=001 Check=TYPE1
09-14 14:02:03.818 3562-3562/? D/METHDO2: Raw Query returned 1 Rows using SQL=SELECT  * FROM users WHERE keyuseridentry='001'
09-14 14:02:03.818 3562-3562/? D/METHOD3: Rows in Cursor = 1 Based upon Search criteria ===>001<===
09-14 14:02:03.818 3562-3562/? D/METHOD3: Add User IDCode=001 Check=TYPE1
09-14 14:02:03.822 3562-3562/? D/METHOD1: Rows in Cursor = 0 Based upon Search criteria ===>003<===
09-14 14:02:03.822 3562-3562/? D/METHDO1: Raw Query returned 0 Rows using SQL=SELECT  * FROM users WHERE keyuseridentry=003
09-14 14:02:03.822 3562-3562/? D/METHOD2: Rows in Cursor = 1 Based upon Search criteria ===>003<===
09-14 14:02:03.822 3562-3562/? D/METHOD2: Add User IDCode=003 Check=TYPE3
09-14 14:02:03.823 3562-3562/? D/METHDO2: Raw Query returned 1 Rows using SQL=SELECT  * FROM users WHERE keyuseridentry='003'
09-14 14:02:03.824 3562-3562/? D/METHOD3: Rows in Cursor = 1 Based upon Search criteria ===>003<===
09-14 14:02:03.825 3562-3562/? D/METHOD3: Add User IDCode=003 Check=TYPE3
```

---

#### Offsets (potential alternative cause for the issue)

In the **`addUsersToList`** method you may spot that instead of hard coded offsfets I've used the `getColumnIndex(column name as String)` method to get the offsets based upon the column names. This can significantly reduce the potential for errors converting columns to offsets.

For example, it could be that your **`KEY_USER_ID_ENTRY`** is the first column in the table, if so it's offset would be 0 not 1. This could also result in no rows being found.